# Home partition not showing in Files sidebar

Tags: files

In Files on the sidebar, my Home partition is not showing.  I see "File System" which is on its own partition, under the "Devices" header but no Home partition represented.  I also have an NAS hard drive which is showing under the "Network" header.  I would like to have it so I can get a quick read on its free space situation.

elementary Loki

Comment: In linux you will have it that way. Everything under File System. You should use the command `df` to attain what you are looking for. For usage of `df` to obtain the space situation of any partition you should run `man df` to learn all the options. For disk usage you have also `du` but `df` is more convenient for the usage you refer.

Answer (score 1):

**TL; DR: add `x-gvfs-show` to mount options**

Actually none of the partitions mounted permanently (except the / partition) shows up in this Devices list, only external USB or network drives.

At least, this is the default behavior you can change this by adding `x-gvfs-show` to the mount options in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=f5aa03f7-28a4-435e-84d6-d84529f13532 /home       ext4    defaults,x-gvfs-show  0   2
```

Answer (score -1):

Your home is in File System under /home/

You should have your home folders in Personal tab. :)

Comment: I am talking about the Home partition, not folder.  I do have the Home folder displayed.  I have separate root & Home partitions.  All that shows in the sidebar is the File System (root) partition.  Can't understand why Home partition does not appear.